# Draw a line to the given point and degrees on a view in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, cgpath

i have a situation where the user will tap on the screen and enters the degrees and a line should to be draw from the tapped point in the given degree.

i am using the following path code to draw the line but i am not able to draw the line in the correct degree.

```
 CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
 CGPathMoveToPoint(path,NULL,touchx,touchy);
 CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,endX, endY);
 lineLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
 [lineLayer setPath:path];
 [lineLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor lightTextColor] CGColor]];
 [lineLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
 [lineLayer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
 [lineLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
 [drawingview.layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
 CGPathRelease(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

You posted code that creates a path with a start point, and and end point, but did not post the most important bit: how you calculate the end point.

I assume that's the part you need help with.

You need to use basic trigonometry. Trig on iOS is based on radians, so you will need to convert degrees to radians:

```
CGFloat radians = M_PI * degrees / 180.0;
```

Then you need to calculate your end point based on your start point.

Remember the mnemonic of the Indian chief "SOH CAH TOA" (sine = opposite/hypotenuse, cosine = adjacent/hypotenuse, tangent = opposite/adjacent).

Drawing a diagram of a right triangle with the angle in question on the left and the right angle on the right:

[image]

The X measurement is the adjacent side.

So, if cosine = adjacent/hypotenuse, then adjacent = cos * hypotenuse.

The hypotenuse of the triangle is the radius of the circle. Replacing variables:

```
x = cos(angle) * radius
```

The y measurement is the opposite side.

If sine = opposite/hypotenuse, then opposite = sine * hypotenuse.

The hypotenuse of the triangle is the radius of the circle. Replacing variables:

```
y = sin(angle) * radius
```

So your code to calculate the end-point might look like this:

```
CGFloat radius = 50; //Picked out of thin air; decide on a radius value

CGFloat deltaX = radius * cosf(radians);
CGFloat deltaY = radius * sinf(radians);

endX = touchX+deltaX;
endy = touchY+deltaY;
```